# Zenity: HOW TO create a user and change its password?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, root, zenity

I'm new to zenity and would like to create a GUI for creating a new user and password. My code goes like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
zenity --info --text='Welcome to Account Creation Wizard'
zenity --entry --text='What do you want to set your username as?' > username
zenity --password > test
cat username >> username1
cat username >> username1
cat test >> test1
cat test >> test1
useradd -m < username1
passwd < username1 < test1
rm test test1
rm username username1
exit
```

But it does not work. In the terminal, I get this:

```
[root@archevaris Desktop]# ./UserCreator.sh
Usage: useradd [options] LOGIN
       useradd -D
       useradd -D [options]

Options:
      --badnames                do not check for bad names
  -b, --base-dir BASE_DIR       base directory for the home directory of the
                                new account
      --btrfs-subvolume-home    use BTRFS subvolume for home directory
  -c, --comment COMMENT         GECOS field of the new account
  -d, --home-dir HOME_DIR       home directory of the new account
  -D, --defaults                print or change default useradd configuration
  -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE  expiration date of the new account
  -f, --inactive INACTIVE       password inactivity period of the new account
  -g, --gid GROUP               name or ID of the primary group of the new
                                account
  -G, --groups GROUPS           list of supplementary groups of the new
                                account
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -k, --skel SKEL_DIR           use this alternative skeleton directory
  -K, --key KEY=VALUE           override /etc/login.defs defaults
  -l, --no-log-init             do not add the user to the lastlog and
                                faillog databases
  -m, --create-home             create the user's home directory
  -M, --no-create-home          do not create the user's home directory
  -N, --no-user-group           do not create a group with the same name as
                                the user
  -o, --non-unique              allow to create users with duplicate
                                (non-unique) UID
  -p, --password PASSWORD       encrypted password of the new account
  -r, --system                  create a system account
  -R, --root CHROOT_DIR         directory to chroot into
  -P, --prefix PREFIX_DIR       prefix directory where are located the /etc/* files
  -s, --shell SHELL             login shell of the new account
  -u, --uid UID                 user ID of the new account
  -U, --user-group              create a group with the same name as the user

New password: Retype new password: passwd: password updated successfully
[root@archevaris Desktop]#
```

And what it actually did was change my root password :P (This bash script is kinda dangerous to execute but thankfully I did it in a VM snapshot)

So, how to fix this? What changes should I make in the code?

Comment: You should probably check the manpages: if those commands don’t read from standard in, redirecting it won’t work.

Comment: I think implementing a GUI for shell scripts isn't that hard (Haven't tried it before) Especially using zenity. But I don't get how to do it. [Forum link](https://www.linux.org/threads/zenity-create-new-user-and-password-creator.27501/) Oh and that was me in that forum. I asked a question there but I haven't got a reply yet..

Answer (score 1):

To get a username and password via `zenity`, this will work:

```
export INFO=$(zenity --password --username)
```

$INFO will be split by a pipe, so if your username is "Fred" and your password is "123abc", $INFO will look like this:

```
Fred|123abc
```

From here, just use `cut` to separate the data:

```
USERNAME=$(echo $INFO | cut -d"|" -f1)
PASSWORD=$(echo $INFO | cut -d"|" -f2)
```